# Woocommerce: Display a quantity in cart count for each item in the cart

Tags: woocommerce

I've been trying to get my head around this for a while now. I'm trying to achieve an item count which lets the customer know the quantity of the item(s) already in the cart and the quantity that has just been added to the cart. For example if they add to cart 4 croissants it should say "You have 4 in your basket" and if there is already 2 pain au Chocolat it should "You have 2 in your basket". This needs to display on the shop page below the product.

With the aid of multiple resources I've got the on page load part working using PHP:

```php
// Hook to display the item count underneath each product in the shop loop
add_action('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'display_product_item_count', 10, 3);

// Function to display the item count for a product
function display_product_item_count($add_to_cart_html, $product, $args) {
    if (is_page('Order & collect')) {
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $item_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities();
    
    if (isset($item_count[$product_id])) {
        $count = $item_count[$product_id];
        $count_html = '<div class="product-count product-count-' . $product_id . '">You have <span class="product-count product-count-' . $product_id . '">' . $count . '</span> in your basket</div>';
        return $add_to_cart_html . $count_html;
    }
    
    return $add_to_cart_html;
    }
}
```

I need it so that if the item count is changed i.e. an item is added or removed from the cart, the item count updates without reloading the page. Also if an item is removed from the cart the item count should be hidden. I imagine I'll need to use jQuery for this?

Please can someone point me in the right direction!

### EDIT: Updated working code:

```php
// Add action to display the item count underneath each product in the shop loop
add_action('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'display_product_item_count', 10, 3);

// Function to display the item count for a product
function display_product_item_count($add_to_cart_html, $product, $args) {
    if (is_page('Order & collect')) {
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        $item_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities();

        $count_html = '<div class="product-count product-count-' . $product_id . '">';
        
        if (isset($item_count[$product_id])) {
            $count = $item_count[$product_id];
            $count_html .= "You have $count in your basket";
        }

        $count_html .= '</div>';
        
        return $add_to_cart_html . $count_html;
    }

    return $add_to_cart_html;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_update_all_product_item_counts', 'update_all_product_item_counts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_all_product_item_counts', 'update_all_product_item_counts');

function update_all_product_item_counts() {
    $item_counts = array();
    
    // Get all product IDs in the specified category
    $args = array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'status' => 'publish',
        'return' => 'ids',
        'category' => array('baked-goods'),
        'stock_status' => 'instock',
    );
    
    $category_product_ids = wc_get_products($args);
    
    // Loop through cart items and get their quantities
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        $item_counts[$product_id] = $quantity;
    }
    
    // Set quantity to 0 for products in the category not in the cart
    foreach ($category_product_ids as $product_id) {
        if (!isset($item_counts[$product_id])) {
            $item_counts[$product_id] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    // Send the item counts as JSON
    wp_send_json($item_counts);
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'product_count_order_page');

function product_count_order_page() {
    if (is_page('Order & collect')) {
?>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    function updateProductItemCount(product_id, count) {
        if (count > 0) {
            $('.product-count-' + product_id).html('You have ' + count + ' in your basket');
        } else {
            $('.product-count-' + product_id).html('');
        }
    }

    function updateAllProductItemCounts() {
         var adminAjaxUrl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            url: adminAjaxUrl,
            data: {
                action: 'update_all_product_item_counts',
            },
            success: function(response) {
                for (var product_id in response) {
                    updateProductItemCount(product_id, response[product_id]);
                }
            },
        });
    }

    $(document.body).on('added_to_cart removed_from_cart', function() {
        updateAllProductItemCounts();
    });

    $(window).on('pageshow', function(event) {
        if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
            updateAllProductItemCounts();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<?php
    }
}
```

- Item count displays on page load if the item is in the cart
- Create Ajax function which fetches all in stock items in the category. Loops through cart items and gets their quantities and sets quantity to 0 for products in the category not in the cart.
- jQuery calls Ajax function using existing Woocommerce JS hooks which loops through product ids and uses item count in the response to adjust `$('.product-count-' + product_id)` accordingly.

Hopefully this helps someone else!